# How to use Get command in Monkey talk?

Tags: monkeytalk

Does anybody know how to use the Get command in monkey talk?

In monkey talk guide only the command is written but no syntax is present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you,

`var x = app.label("label1").get("x","value")`

Above line will get the value of label1 and store it in variable x. You can change the second parameter "value" to ".text" or ".size" depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

since the question is not marked Answered and For the future reference i am answering this.

‘GET’ ACTION RETRIEVES COMPONENT PROPERTY VALUES

Syntax:
ComponenType MonkeyId Get varName propName
Works like an assignment statement (varName= propName)

The default property is “value”

// Get label value currently displayed

Label lastname Get name

// Enter name into input field

Input query EnterText ${name}

// Get the first table item

Table countries Get country items[1](http://www.stickyminds.com/sites/default/files/presentation/file/2014/T16.pdf)

// Enter into input field

Input * EnterText ${country}
you can refer this document [here](http://www.stickyminds.com/sites/default/files/presentation/file/2014/T16.pdf), thanqs

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain using example. Suppose there is a ListView(Table) and you want to scroll till its last item.

```
//Define a variable
Vars * Define row

//Store size of list in variable row using Get. Check use of "Get" here
Table * Get row size %thinktime=20000

//Now stored variable can be used as per need. here I am using for scrolling
Table * ScrollToRow ${row} %thinktime=2000
```

Hope it helps you !!